# Using a downloaded .class file in an intellij project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I'm supposed to:

- Have all .java files and cs2030.simulator package directly under src
- Use RandomGenerator.class, which is in cs2030.simulator package
- Have RngCustom reference RandomGenerator
- Have RngCustom's class file compiled into cs2030.simulator package

In intellij, however, I am getting errors, intellij wants to move the .java into the package, and cannot resolve RandomGenerator.
Even though intellij shows errors, I am able to compile using `javac -d . *.java`, which places the compiled .class into the package

[image]

Even if I move the RngCustom.java file into the package, intellij is still unable to resolve RandomGenerator
[image]

Comment: Your package name seems not correct.

Comment: add src folder to classpath

Comment: src is currently sources root, how to I add it to classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this `RngCustom file in package cs2030.simulator`.

As you can see in intellij itself, that the path of **RngCustom file** is `Project3/src/` .

Change the path to `Project3/src/cs2030/simulator`

Comment: please refer to the second image, it is already in the package

Comment: now put the package name that was previously there, i.e. cs2030.simulator in place of simulator.

Comment: Then you will be able to import RandonGenerator. Comment again if that didn't work

Comment: Don't put .class file there put the simple RngCustom file at that location where you have kept RngCustom.class.  Are you aware of Concept of Packaging in java ?

Comment: RngCustom.java is still in src folder, move it to src/cs2030/simulator

Comment: Instructions from the tutors were that the .java should not be in the package. Even if I move the RngCustom.java file into the package, intellij is still unable to resolve RandomGenerator

Comment: Just take RngCustom.java in this src/cs2030/simulator folder, it can import all the classes in that package.

Comment: Where is RandomGenerator.java file ?

Comment: https://github.com/nakulGoyal19/SpringBootLearning/tree/master/course-api    Refer this, for knowing where to put .java files                 You can have a target folder which will automatically have all .class files after compilation.

Comment: Please refer to second image, even when RngCustom.java is in src/cs2030/simulator, it is unable to import the class. There is no RandomGenerator.java provided.

Comment: You need to have RandomGenerator.java for that. And in second image put the first line as ------>
        package cs2030.simulator;